# Counting instances in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with millions of records. Records look like this:

```
   name    group
+--------+------+
|  aaa   |   1  |
|  bbb   |   2  |
|  ccc   |   1  |
|  aaa   |   1  |
|  aaa   |   2  |
+--------+------+
```

- Each name can be repeated multiple times in one group.
- Each name can be in multiple groups.
- There are a lot of groups

I need to display a "report" with following information:

1. How many times each name occure in the table (sorted from highest to lowest).
2. How many times these names occure in each group.

Of course, I won't display information for all names, so I want to display only first 100 names (with the most occurences).

Example of desired output:

```
  name   count   group1  group2
+------+-------+-------+-------+
| aaa  |   3   |   2   |   1   |
| bbb  |   1   |   0   |   1   |
| ccc  |   1   |   1   |   0   |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

So far, I counted names using this query:

```
select * from 
    (select name, count(name) as count from Names s 
     group by name order by count desc) r 
limit 100
```

I cannot figure out how to count the names returned by above query in each group.

Comment: You have no PK. This could prove problematic. And `group` is a reserved word, so (IMO) a poor choice for a table/column identifier.

Comment: If you want a dynamic number of columns you will need to generate the query dynamically for the specific groups you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mysql, you can use a shorthand as follows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,name    VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,category INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (name,category) VALUES
('aaa',1),
('bbb',2),
('ccc',1),
('aaa',1),
('aaa',2);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+------+----------+
| id | name | category |
+----+------+----------+
|  1 | aaa  |        1 |
|  2 | bbb  |        2 |
|  3 | ccc  |        1 |
|  4 | aaa  |        1 |
|  5 | aaa  |        2 |
+----+------+----------+


SELECT name
     , COUNT(*) total
     , SUM(category = 1) cat1
     , SUM(category = 2) cat2 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY name;
+------+-------+------+------+
| name | total | cat1 | cat2 |
+------+-------+------+------+
| aaa  |     3 |    2 |    1 |
| bbb  |     1 |    0 |    1 |
| ccc  |     1 |    1 |    0 |
+------+-------+------+------+
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I just added `ORDER BY total DESC` and `LIMIT 100` to achieve desired output

Answer (score 1):

Use `Conditional Aggregate`. Try this.

```
SELECT name,
       Count(1) as `count`,
       Count(CASE
               WHEN `group` = 1 THEN 1
             END) group1,
       Count(CASE
               WHEN `group` = 2 THEN 1
             END) group2
FROM   yourtable
GROUP  BY name
```